# Rails tests with various integrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, testing, salesforce

I have a rails app that interacts with an external api (Salesforce) that relies upon external data sitting in a remote database. I've written a wrapper that wraps this code so that users can just call `get_by_id(id)` instead of writing the corresponding sql query.

I want to test this code, and I am not sure how I should go about it. Should I be hitting the Salesforce backend database for the tests, calling the real methods? Or should I just mock the results of the method calls? I am perpetually confused by what I should test...

Answer (score 1):

You should write like a suite for Salesforce's interaction.

A basic principle of testing, is that your test should not fail because of external factors. However, your app should be able to recover from SalesForce's  errors.

From [Rails 4 Test Prescriptions](https://pragprog.com/book/nrtest2/rails-4-test-prescriptions)

> Unfortunately, interacting with a third-party web service introduces a
>   lot of complexity to our testing. Connecting to a web service is
>   slow—even slower than the database connections we’ve already tried to
>   avoid. Plus, connection to a web service requires an Internet
>   connection... Some external services are public—we don’t want to post an update to Twitter every time we run our tests, let alone post a credit-card payment to PayPal.

Also, the book has some guidelines,

> A fake server, which intercepts HTTP requests during a test and
>   returns a canned response object. We’ll be using the VCR gem ...* An
>   adapter, which is an object that sits between the client and the
>   server to mediate access between them.
>
> A smoke test, which goes from the client all the way to the real server...a full end-to-end test of the entire interaction. We don’t
>   want to do this often, for all the reasons listed earlier, but it’s
>   useful to be able to guard against changes in the server API.
>
> An integration test, which goes from the client to the fake server.
>   This tests the entire end-to-end functionality of our application but
>   uses a stubbed response from the server.
>
> A client unit test, which starts on the client and ends in the
>   adapter. The adapter’s responses are stubbed, meaning that the adapter
>   isn’t even making fake server calls. This allows us to unit-test our
>   client completely separate from the server API.
>
> An adapter unit test, which starts in the adapter and ends in the
>   fake server. These tests are the final piece of the chain and allow us
>   to validate the behavior of the adapter separate from any client or
>   the actual server

By the way, I think the book is a must-have